# Terraform: how to implement Application Security Groups in Azure RM

Tags: azure, terraform, application-security

## Problem

I discovered that I can [integrate Application Security Groups (ASG) into a Network Interface when using the `azurestack` resource provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurestack/latest/docs/resources/network_interface), but I [cannot do so when using the `azurerm` resource provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/network_interface).

## My Understanding

I do not understand why I cannot.  I actually do not understand the difference between Azure Stack and Azure RM.  [This article](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-provider-for-azure-stack) suggests that Azure Stack is for hybrid deployments and Azure RM (or Azure Provider) is for pure cloud deployments.

All the previous work that I and other colleagues have done has been with `azurerm`.  I would prefer to stick with `azurerm` if I could. Or, if possible, I would like to "mix and match" `azurerm` and `azurestack`, using `azurestack` only when I have to, like in this case. But I'd really like to know why some things are only possible with one provider, since they both should have the same offering, with respect to pure Azure services.

---

## Any Ideas?

Ultimately, though, I am just trying to solve the problem of attaching a network interface to a VM, where the NIC has associated ASGs. I would like to do this with `azurerm` if possible. I can do it with `azurestack`, as long as `azurestack` is compatible with other services launched through `azurerm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `azurestack` to associate NIC with ASGs

Terraform provider `azurerm` has resource called `azurerm_network_interface_application_security_group_association`

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_application_security_group_association

You just need to create ASG and associate it with NIC.

Example:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_application_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-asg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_application_security_group_association" "example" {
  network_interface_id          = azurerm_network_interface.example.id
  application_security_group_id = azurerm_application_security_group.example.id
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This interface seems a little strange; it is so different from how the ARM template handles ASGs.  But I got it to work.  Appreciate the help.  :)